# Generate header files for an app having space in their app name

Tags: ios, applescript, scripting-bridge

I am looking to generate a header file for "App Store" app. Referring Apple's documentation on Scripting Bridge, I was able to generate the header file for iTunes and Safari apps:

```
sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename iTunes
sdef /Applications/Safari.app | sdp -fh --basename Safari
```

I tried the following for App Store app:

```
Command - sdef /Applications/AppStore.app | sdp -fh --basename AppStore
Error - sdef: couldn't get sdef for /Applications/AppStore.app (error -43)
Error - sdp: stdin - zero length data

Command - sdef /Applications/App Store.app | sdp -fh --basename App Store
Error - usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/sdef file
Error - sdp: Store - The file “Store” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

How do I generate the header file for App Store?

Comment: admittedly I don't know the process you're talking about, but typically in POSIX path, if you're dealing with a space, you either need to escape it or surround it in quotes. **/Applications/App\ Store.app** or **"/Applications/App Store.app"**

Comment: Awesome /Applications/App\ Store.app worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic unix shell problem. In a shell, a space separates commands from arguments. You might either quote or use the backslash escape character like:

`$ sdef /Applications/App\ Store.app | sdp -fh --basename App\ Store`

or

`$ sdef "/Applications/App Store.app" | sdp -fh --basename "App Store"`

NOTE: that the attribute App Store must also be quoted, so the shell knows that this is one token.